# VBA code does not work in all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following code that takes a record of the busiest hour of each day from sheet and adds it to another. The code works in all sheets that I've tried it on except one (all the sheets are similar).

My question is, is there any reason why this is the case? Could it be because of formatting?

```
Sub DailySales()
Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest          store activity
Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the   highest period of each day
Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
Dim maxCustomerRng As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
Dim CheckForDups As Range ' Used to find duplicate dates on the record Sheet
Dim maxCustomerCnt As Long ' value of highest customer count

Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supermarket Data")

Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Record Data")
With recordSht
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)))
    Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(7, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not maxCustomerRng Is Nothing Then
        Set CheckForDups = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1)
    End If
End With

Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
Set dailySht = Nothing
Set recordSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

The table is in the following format:

```
Customer data   7:00:00 AM  7:30:00 AM  8:00:00 AM  8:30:00 AM  9:00:00 AM  
Number of customers 33         37         110          250        84
Amount spent        65         50          70           85        60
Average time spent  12         10           8           17        10
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid description.

Comment: How many columns do you have on that specific sheet?

Comment: @GSerg it does not copy the data from 'Supermarket Data' into 'Record Data'

Comment: What is the error? Does it show wrong results / does it stop with a message box showing an error code / Blue Screen Of Death / etc.? How is the Worksheet that does not work different from the others (including its location, name)? If the error is shown by a message box, did you click on Debug, and did you check the actual value of the variables?

Comment: @Vityata it has 49 columns

Comment: @z32a7ul it does not bring up any error message, nothing is displayed. The only difference is the number of columns (49) and the number of rows (18). They're all in the same location. Debugging the code shows the correct values, it just does not copy them into the second sheet.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see what happens when running the code...

Comment: First of all, break the line starting with If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then into two rows, and set a break point at the If statement. Run the code with the wrong sheet and when your break point is hit, check whether the line with Copy gets executed. If not then something was wrong in the condition of the If, otherwise there is a problem in the If branch - let VBA print the address of both the source and the destination range.

Comment: @z32a7ul adding a breakpoint does not execute the Copy

Comment: That means CheckForDups is not Nothing, so Find did return a valid Range. According to the name, this may be a check whether there are duplicate values on the sheet. I do not know the business logic behind this code, so you should clarify why this checking is needed.

Comment: The check is needed because the report is generated once a day which displays hourly records of each 24 hour preriod.  I want to keep a record of the busiest hour of each day in a separate sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options why it does not work:

- You have a space in the name of the tab and you do not realize it (see the picture)
  [image]
- You have a chart with exactly the same name as the sheet (But I doubt!)
- The format in the sheet is different. Take a look at the hard coded values here (2,1,7, etc.) and check
  whether they make sense it it:

---

```
maxCustomerCnt = Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)))
Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(7, lColDaily)).Find(What:=...
```

Comment: The tab names don't have any space, I haven't got a chart with the same name as the sheet and values are correct.

Comment: @aab - start pressing F8 and see what it does.

Comment: It shows that ".Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)" obtains the correct value. It just does not get copied into the second sheet

Comment: @aab - write `debug.print maxCustomerRng.address` after this row and see what you get in the immediate window.

Comment: This is what I get: $W$2

Comment: Yes it's fine. That's the column that is supposed to be copied (based on that value - the highest value)

Comment: @aab - then a few lines lower write `debug.print CheckForDups.address`

Comment: I get $W$1 this time, the date.

Comment: Yes it is fine.

Comment: @aab - press `F8` twice and see which column are you copying.

Comment: Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supermarket Data")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152763/discussion-between-aab-and-vityata).